# using sql to select records based on date differences

Tags: sql, datediff

I manage a system that records changes in it's stock item's price and quantity.

The table would look like this:

```
STOCK(ID, DATE, QUANTITY, PRICE)

(1, 2013.01.07 00:00, 9, 6)
(1, 2013.01.02 00:00, 9, 5)
(1, 2013.01.01 00:00, 10, 5)
(2, 2013.01.07 22:00, 20, 10)
(2, 2013.01.07 00:00, 24, 10)
(3, 2013.01.02 00:00, 9, 5)
(3, 2013.01.01 00:00, 10, 5)
```

The query to return changes over 1 day period should return the information for the latest history record for an item and the information for the history record that differs at most 1 day from it (or itself if there is none):

```
STOCK(ID, DATE_BEFORE, DATE_AFTER, QUANTITY_BEFORE, QUANTITY_AFTER, PRICE_BEFORE, PRICE_AFTER)
(1, 2013.01.07 00:00, 2013.01.07 00:00, 9, 9, 6, 6)
(2, 2013.01.07 00:00, 2013.01.07 22:00, 24, 20, 10, 10)
(3, 2013.01.01 00:00, 2013.01.02 00:00, 10, 9, 5, 5)
```

The query to return changes over 1 week period should return the information for the latest history record for an item and the information for the history record that differs at most 7 days from it (or itself if there is none):

```
STOCK(ID, DATE_BEFORE, DATE_AFTER, QUANTITY_BEFORE, QUANTITY_AFTER, PRICE_BEFORE, PRICE_AFTER)
(1, 2013.01.01 00:00, 2013.01.07 00:00, 10, 9, 5, 6)
(2, 2013.01.07 00:00, 2013.01.07 22:00, 24, 20, 10, 10)
(3, 2013.01.01 00:00, 2013.01.02 00:00, 10, 9, 5, 5)
```

I hope this is clear enough, as I know it's not an easy topic.

Looking forward to hearing you comments.

Thanks in advance,

H

Comment: Which database are you using, and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: What is the table unique key? And it looks like you are missing an output row for rows 2 and 3 of ID=1 for the "one day" result

Comment: @Ian Kenney Hello. I'm using hypersonic 2.2.9

Comment: @gbn Regarding the PK, I'm sory to say that I forgot about it. There is a seuqence in place and the example records would be keys with numbers 1 through 7. The results are not missing. The query only regards the latest record for a given STOCK.ID for the AFTER_* information.

Comment: @Ian Kenney So far I've been trying to use subqueries to do this, but thus far haven't come up with nothing userful and we are talking about page long queries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I am not familiar with hypersonic sql dialect.

The following may help you get where you need, it seems to get what you want on mysql.

```
select subq.*, 
  st_before.quantity QUANTITY_BEFORE, 
  st_after.quantity QUANTITY_AFTER,  
  st_before.price PRICE_BEFORE,
  st_after.price PRICE_AFTER
from ( 
  select 
    max_id stock_id, 
    date_before,
    date_after 
  from
  (
    SELECT id max_id,max(date) date_after
    FROM STOCK
    GROUP BY ID 
  ) mx
  join 
  (  
    SELECT stock.id min_id,min(stock.date) date_before
    FROM STOCK 
    join (
       SELECT id,max(date) date_after
       FROM STOCK
       GROUP BY ID 
    ) mmx
    on stock.id = mmx.id
    and datediff(mmx.date_after, stock.date) < 1
    GROUP BY stock.ID 
  ) mn 
  on  mx.max_id = mn.min_id 
  ) subq 
  join stock st_before 
  on st_before.id = subq.stock_id 
  and st_before.date = subq.date_before 
  join stock st_after 
  on st_after.id = subq.stock_id 
  and st_after.date = subq.date_after 
  order by stock_id
;
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41edf/58)